# How do I position unordered list in the navbar div thats inside a header div?

Tags: html, css, layout

I am trying to work on just the navigation bar.  I am having trouble positioning the unordered list thats in the navbar to position it on the bottom of the header.  I tried using overflow hidden and also moving it with padding.  Still no luck. How do I do it?

```css
    body{
     height:100%;
     margin: 0;
     background-color:#cccccc;
    }
    #container{
     width:100%;
     height:auto;
    }
    #header{
     width:100%;
     height:50px;
     background-color:white;
     margin: auto;
    
    }
    .logo{
     font-weight:bold;
     width:8%;
     height:20px;
     float:left;
     font-size: 20px;
    }
    .navbar{
     width:75%;
     height:40px;
     margin: auto;
     
    }
    .navbar ul{
     list-style-type: none;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     height:20px;
     width:18%;
    
    }
    .navbar li{
     float:left;
     padding-right:10px;
     display:block;
    }
    li a{
     
     font-size:18px;
     font-family:tahoma;
     font-weight:italic;
     text-decoration:none;
    }
    li a:hover{
     text-decoration:none;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>test2</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="container">
      <div id="header">
       <div class="logo">Hello</div>
       
       <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
         <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
         <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
         <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Remove `width: 18%` from `.navbar ul`

Comment: "to position it on the bottom of the header" - so, do you need to display below the logo?

Comment: Your remove 18% width fixed the problem.  Thank you.  Thanks to everyone else who answered.

Answer (score 1):

remove width in this below class

```
.navbar ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;


}
```

**[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tdj76950/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It should help you.
Position navbar relative and Position ul absolute and 48px from top.

```
.navbar{
width:75%;
height:40px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
}
.navbar ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:20px;
width:18%;
position:absolute;
top:48px;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/yJYRxa)

Answer (score 0):

just remove `float:left` from `.logo` and `margin:auto` from `.navbar`

[JSFIddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bk3nk95u/)